# Can I make a grouped or stacked bar chart in plotly from a value_counts() expression

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have a dataframe with the columns - Team, GPU and Exit code. I grouped values by team and exit code to get a count of number of exit codes for each team. I did the same for GPU and exit codes.

here's my dataframe and here's the expression for value_counts().

```
df

Exit Code   GPU    Team   
  0         gpu1    t1
  0.        gpu3.   t1
  1.        gpu1.   t1
  0         gpu4.   t1
  123.      gpu1.   t2
  0.        gpu4.   t2
```

I used the expression to make a plot but the plot looks clunky:

```
s = df.groupby('team')['Exit Code'].value_counts()
s.plot(kind='bar')
```

How can I make a neat plot with value counts as the y-axis and team name as x-axis and the exit code in different colors using plotly?